# How can I convert a MUS file to a MIDI file

Tags: conversion, file-format, midi, audio-conversion

I have a bunch of .mus files to .mid format to import them into Guitar Pro 6. Does anyone know of a currently working method?

Comment: After some research, the mus file that I have is a DOOM mus file format.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a repository here: https://github.com/pgimeno/mmus2mid which contains a program that should be easy to compile into a mus-to-mid converter. It takes the complete file name of the .mus file; for generating the output file name, it will strip the extension and add its own .mid one. The makefile uses GCC; change it if necessary.

If you need to compile it in a big endian machine, see README.md.